# Writing a program that takes a date as input and outputs the date's season or invalid

Tags: python-3.x

Ex: If the input is:
April
11
the output is: Spring

In addition, check if the string and int are valid (an actual month and day). Ex: If the input is:
Blue
65
the output is: Invalid

The dates for each season are:
Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

Here is my question, everything works fine except month that end on the 30th (April, June, September and November).  Right now if I input June 31 the output should be 'Invaild' but it is not showing any output.  I put my code in below, any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
    month = input('Enter month: ')
    day = int(input('Enter day: '))

    months  = [
'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
]
    
    if month not in months or (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
        print('Invalid')
```

## Spring

```
    elif (month == 'March' and day >= 20 or month == 'April' and day <= 30 or \
          month == 'May' and day or month == 'June' and day <= 20):
        if (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
            print('Invalid')
        else:
            print('Spring')
```

## Summer

```
    elif (month == 'June' and day >= 21 and day <= 30 or month == 'July'and day or \
          month == 'August' and day or month == 'September' and day <= 21):
        if (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
           print('Invalid')
        else:
           print('Summer')
```

## Autumn

```
    elif (month == 'September' and day >= 22 and day <= 30 or \
          month == 'October' and day or month == 'November' and day <= 30 or \
          month == 'December' and day <= 20):
        if (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
           print('Invalid')
        else:
           print('Autumn')
```

## Winter

```
    elif (month == 'December' and day >= 21 and day <= 31 or \
          month == 'January' and day or month == 'February' and day or \
          month == 'March' and day <= 19 and day >= 31):
        if (day <= 0) and (day > 31):
           print('Invalid')
        else:
           print('Winter')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the `elif` statements, add a final `else` statement to catch the errors and mention that as `print("Invalid")`
Also, please keep the various `or` and `and` inside the `elif` statements within brackets, so that there is no confusion/error as to which one gets picked first.
Do check the pharse `month == 'May' and day or month`... think you missed `day < 30`. This is in all 4 `elif` statements

**EDIT**

Updated code as requested...

```
month = input('Enter month: ')
day = int(input('Enter day: '))

months  = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    
if month not in months or (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
    print('Invalid')

elif ((month == 'March' and day >= 20) or (month == 'April' and day <= 30) or \
      (month == 'May') or (month == 'June' and day <= 20)):
    if (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Spring')
elif ((month == 'June' and day >= 21 and day <= 30) or (month == 'July') or \
      (month == 'August') or (month == 'September' and day <= 21)):
    if (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
       print('Invalid')
    else:
       print('Summer')
    
elif ((month == 'September' and day >= 22 and day <= 30) or \
      (month == 'October') or (month == 'November' and day <= 30) or \
      (month == 'December' and day <= 20)):
    if (day <= 0) or (day > 31):
       print('Invalid')
    else:
       print('Autumn')
elif ((month == 'December' and day >= 21) or \
      (month == 'January') or (month == 'February' and day<=28) or \
      (month == 'March' and day <= 19)):
    if (day <= 0) and (day > 31):
       print('Invalid')
    else:
       print('Winter')
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Added the updated code